# Get all users who have permission to a specific folder

Tags: 2010, development, permissions, ssom

I am working with SharePoint 2010 . I have a folder in my SharePoint document library. I am trying to get the **users** who have any permission or role to that folder programmatically. But can't find a way to get the list of these users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using CSOM or SOM?

Comment: using Server Side Object Model.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code snippet

```
public static void getPermissionsOfFolders()
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList list = web.GetList("/Lists/List2");
                foreach (SPListItem item in list.Folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID: "+item["ID"]+"--"+item.SortType);
                    if (SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder == item.SortType)
                    {
                        SPRoleAssignmentCollection roles = item.RoleAssignments;
                        foreach (SPRoleAssignment role in roles)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("~");
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: "+role.Member.Name);

                            SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection bindings = role.RoleDefinitionBindings;

                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                            doc.LoadXml(bindings.Xml);
                            XmlNodeList itemList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Role");
                            foreach (XmlNode currNode in itemList)
                            {
                                string s = currNode.Attributes["Name"].Value.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine("Permission Level: "+s);
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                    }  
                }                                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Found same from the link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8c7c5735-039e-4cb9-a2b5-58d70a10793f/get-permissions-group-from-folders-tree-view-on-a-doc-library?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Also you can refer to this link for CSOM approach
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163483/code-to-list-all-permissions-for-sharepoint-folders

Comment: As i am working on a folder in document library, so how to get the folder using list?

Comment: U would just give it a try... As folder is also one item and you can check in the code snippet that we are working with folders in the library

Comment: Its giving `FileNotFoundException`  as there is no list named "List2" is not existed in my list. I didn't find any way to get the list which contains the document library folders  using web-part.